# Bounding boxes returned without detected face image in dlib python

Tags: face-recognition, face-detection, dlib, dlib-python, deepface

I'm trying to detect multiple faces in a picture using the deepface library with dlib as the backend detector. I'm using the `DlibWrapper.py` from the deeepface library and i have the following issue: In some cases, the detector returns the bounding box coordinates but doesn't return the detected face image [detected face-box coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ri6C.png).

I was wondering if this bug occurs because of the negative values of some coordinates of the bounding boxes but i figured out that was not the case, as the negative values are features, not bugs. Here is the [DlibWrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmuk0.png) from the deepface library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!There are edge cases where original rectangle is partially outside the image window. That happens with dlib. So, instead of

- detected_face = img[top:bottom, left:right],

the detected face should be

- detected_face = img[max(0, top): min(bottom, img_height), max(0, left): min(right, img_width)]